# How to determine installed Windows Edition using .net

Tags: .net, version

System.Environment.OSVersion does not appear to indicate which Edition of Windows 2003 is installed (Standard, Enterprise, DataCenter).

Is there any way to access this information using managed code only?

I know I can use P/Invoke to call GetVersionEx and examine OSVERSIONINFOEX.wSuiteMask to get this info, but I'm looking for a simpler solution.

**Update**

Using WMI looks like the way to go, though the OSProductSuite property of Win32_OperatingSystem looks more reliable than the Name property.  Here's sample code:

```
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope();
ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT name, csdversion, description, OperatingSystemSKU, OSProductSuite FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");

using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query))
{
    using (ManagementObjectCollection resultCollection = searcher.Get())
    {
        foreach (ManagementObject result in resultCollection)
        {
            foreach (PropertyData propertyData in result.Properties)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(
                    propertyData.Name + ": " +
                    ((propertyData.Value == null) ? "" : propertyData.Value.ToString())
                    );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The pinvoke way seems pretty simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could execute the following WMI query:

SELECT name FROM Win32_OperatingSystem

It returns something like this:

Microsoft Windows Server 2003 Standard Edition|C:\WINDOWS|\Device\Harddisk0\Partition1

[This article](http://www.csharphelp.com/archives2/archive334.html) explains how to perform WMI queries using .NET.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to do this using only managed code.

There is some code [here](http://www.csharp411.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/OSInfo.cs) using [GetVersionEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724451%28VS.85%29.aspx) that should encapsulate things for you nicely though.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add a smaller snippet of code for anyone who needs it.

```
    private static string GetOSName()
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT Caption FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
        foreach (ManagementObject os in searcher.Get())
        {
            result = os["Caption"].ToString();
            break;
        }
        return result;
    }
```